# determine the steady state and their stability of $\frac{dx}{dt}$ = $x²-5x+6$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

**MY ATTEMPT**

To find steady state solution We have $\frac{dx}{dt}$ = 0, solving we get, $x = 2, 3 $ since both points are real , distinct and positive hence points are unstable node.

Is my solution for this question is correct? Please tell me.

Comment: Your conclusion makes absolutely no sense! Are you perhaps confusing this with the criterion where you look at the eigenvalues of the Jacobian matrix to determine the stability of an equilibrium point of a 2-dimensional system? If so, then that's a rather severe mixup, since the *equilibrium points* being positive for a 1-dimensional system is a completely different thing than the *eigenvalues* being positive for a particular equilibrium point in a 2-dimensional system.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\frac{dx}{dt} = x^2-5x+6=(x-2)(x-3)$$
Suppose $\epsilon>0$ is a very small perturbation, then
$$\left[\frac{dx}{dt}\right]_{x=2+\epsilon}=\epsilon\cdot(\epsilon-1)<0$$
$$\left[\frac{dx}{dt}\right]_{x=2-\epsilon}=\epsilon\cdot(\epsilon+1)>0$$
$$\left[\frac{dx}{dt}\right]_{x=3+\epsilon}=\epsilon\cdot(\epsilon+1)>0$$
$$\left[\frac{dx}{dt}\right]_{x=3-\epsilon}=-\epsilon\cdot(1-\epsilon)<0$$
Therefore, $x=2$ is stable, $x=3$ is unstable.